# Como calcular la palabra mas larga de un texto en VB

Tags: vb.net

necesito calcular la palabra mas larga de un texto en Visual Basic, pero solo puedo usar las siguientes funciones: Len, Mid, Instr, Asc, Chr, Trim y Str. Entiendo que una manera es usando Split, pero lamentablemente solo puedo usar la funciones anteriores, alguien tiene alguna idea de como divido las palabras del texto para luego compararlas?

Comment: Bienvenida a la plataforma, te invito a leer [ask] y de paso checar el [tour] para familiarizarte mas con el tipo de preguntas esperadas, en la medida de lo posible trata de editar y mejorar tu publicación

Comment: Indica en la pregunta, algo del código que has intentado para solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recorrer el texto carácter por carácter para determinar donde empieza y acaba cada palabra.

Función **CalcularPalabraMasLarga**

```
Friend Function CalcularPalabraMasLarga(Texto$) As String


    If Texto = "" Then
        Return ""
    End If




    ' Se eliminan los posibles espacios en blanco existentes en el principio o en el final de la cadena.
    Texto = Texto.Trim


    Dim InicioPalabra% = 0
    Dim PalabraMasLargaDetectada As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To Texto.Length - 1

        Dim ElCaracterActualEsSeparadorDePalabra = Texto(i) = " " OrElse  Texto(i) = vbCr OrElse  Texto(i) = vbLf  

        If ElCaracterActualEsSeparadorDePalabra Then



            If InicioPalabra = i Then


                ' Esto suecede cuando hay 2 separados de palabras seguidos

            Else

                Dim PalabraActual = Mid(Texto, InicioPalabra + 1, i - InicioPalabra)
                If PalabraActual.Length > PalabraMasLargaDetectada.Length Then
                    PalabraMasLargaDetectada = PalabraActual
                End If

            End If


        ' La próxima palabra iniciará en el siguiente caracter 
            InicioPalabra = (i + 1)

        End If

    Next



    If InicioPalabra <> Texto.Length - 1 Then

        Dim PalabraFinal = Mid(Texto, InicioPalabra + 1, Texto.Length - InicioPalabra)
        If PalabraFinal.Length > PalabraMasLargaDetectada.Length Then
            PalabraMasLargaDetectada = PalabraFinal
        End If

    End If




    Return PalabraMasLargaDetectada
End Function
```

Ejemplo:

```
    Console.WriteLine(CalcularPalabraMasLarga("teeeeeeexto de prueba para calcular la palabra mas larga"))
    Console.WriteLine(CalcularPalabraMasLarga("  x     prueba teeeeeeexto de prueba para calcular la palabra mas larga"))
    Console.WriteLine(CalcularPalabraMasLarga("  x prueba teeeeeeexto de prueba para calcular la palabra mas larga. hola"))
    Console.WriteLine(CalcularPalabraMasLarga(" de prueba para calcular la palabra mas larga teeeeeeexto"))
```